# 403 error in downloading with URL but works fine in browsers

Tags: java, spring-boot, url

I'm developing a small test to download an apk from apkpure using java.
The URL that I have, returns a 403. But on the browser, it works fine. All solutions I tried did not work.

Here is the code:

```java
URL url = new URL(TheUrl);
try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(in, Paths.get(apkPathInFolder), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    System.out.println("test ok");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

How could I handle it, please ?

Thanks

An example of [the URL](https://download.apkpure.com/b/APK/Y29tLnRlbmNlbnQuaWdfMTU1MjNfYmFhM2U4Njk?_fn=UFVCRyBNT0JJTEUgUkVTSVNUQU5DRV92MS42LjBfYXBrcHVyZS5jb20uYXBr&as=1e5ab5a5ef235ad0674f6ed4f7ff59576150d1cd&ai=33533981&at=1632686421&_sa=ai%2Cat&k=06ee0e1f9f5964c4edc23905822a9c8861537455&_p=Y29tLnRlbmNlbnQuaWc&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION%7CZGV2PVBST1hJTUElMjBCRVRBJnQ9YXBrJnM9MTEzMjQ5NjAwMiZ2bj0xLjYuMCZ2Yz0xNTUyMyZodD1lMDE&ht=e01) I have as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Java user-agent is blocked by some online services. You need to set the `User-Agent` header to something else:

```
    URL url = new URL(httpUrl);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "my-agent");
    httpURLConnection.connect();

    try (InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream()) {
```

Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://download.apkpure.com/b/APK/Y29tLnRlbmNlbnQuaWdfMTU1MjNfYmFhM2U4Njk?_fn=UFVCRyBNT0JJTEUgUkVTSVNUQU5DRV92MS42LjBfYXBrcHVyZS5jb20uYXBr&as=1e5ab5a5ef235ad0674f6ed4f7ff59576150d1cd&ai=33533981&at=1632686421&_sa=ai%2Cat&k=06ee0e1f9f5964c4edc23905822a9c8861537455&_p=Y29tLnRlbmNlbnQuaWc&c=2%7CGAME_ACTION%7CZGV2PVBST1hJTUElMjBCRVRBJnQ9YXBrJnM9MTEzMjQ5NjAwMiZ2bj0xLjYuMCZ2Yz0xNTUyMyZodD1lMDE&ht=e01");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "my-agent");
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        try (InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get("/home/user/Documents/files/my-apk.apk"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Lefretis, i add `httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0");` but still have the same error 403.

Comment: A random user-agent (like `"my-agent"` or `"aaa"`) works for me.

Comment: I just copy your code and try it with the url in the description. It doesnt not work. I use java 8

Comment: Do you have any errors?  I have edited my answer including the full code (JDK 16).

Comment: I have the same error 403. I will try with jdk16. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the header from browser and set it in you code.

if you use chrome browser, open the dev tools in your request page.